# is there a way to bind html tags to some array indices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I need to bind a span with a class to some indices of an array and print that array strings like below example:

```
var mainArray = ["I", "am", "not", "a", "doctor"];
var indices = [1,4]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

i want to get this string result :

```
var result =  "I <span class="bg-light"> am </span > not a <span class="bg-light"> doctor </span>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map` with index.

If `indices` includes `index`, return element wrapped around `span`tag, else return the same element

After that, `join` the result with space

```js
var mainArray = ["I", "am", "not", "a", "doctor"];
var indices = [1,4]

var result = mainArray
  .map((el, index) => indices.includes(index) ? `<span class="bg-light"> ${el} </span>` : el)
  .join(' ')
  
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.bg-light {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```